# Inserting data to mysql, only first date will be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, i have a little problem with this code. Its working fine, but if i try to insert two (or more...) data, its just only first data will be inserted. How can i fix this problem?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    session_start();
    include("db_config.php");
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
    {
    $username=$_SESSION['login_user'];
    $sql[0] = "SELECT * from orders where username='$username'";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql[0]) or die(mysqli_error());

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $name =$record[username];
            $id = $record[id];
            $nmb_products = $record[nmb_products];
            $total_value = $record[total_value];
            $order_date = $record[order_date];
            $city = $record[dest_city];
            $address = $record[address];
        }
    }
    else echo "Failed Access";

    $sql[1] = "INSERT INTO ordered (username,nmb_products,product_id,total_value, city, address) VALUES ('$name', '$nmb_products', '$id', '$total_value', '$city', '$address')";
    $sql[2] = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE username='$username'";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql[1]) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql[2]))
    { 
        header("Location:mypurchases.php");
        exit();
    } 
    }
    else
    echo"Login first";

    $conn->close(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if i try to insert two (or more...) data"

Comment: move `$sql[1] `inside while loop

Comment: I mean, i have another page, and this page have two data and only first one is inserted, other one is just deleted.

Comment: I already tried move $sql[1] inside while, but still dont work

Comment: concatenate the each query with semicolon and excute using mysqli_multi_query

Comment: if you get only one data from $sql[0]  query means don't need foreach there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this part :

```
  $sql[1] = "INSERT INTO ordered (username,nmb_products,product_id,total_value, city, address) VALUES ('$name', '$nmb_products', '$id', '$total_value', '$city', '$address')";
$sql[2] = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE username='$username'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql[1]) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql[2]))
{ 
    header("Location:mypurchases.php");
    exit();
}
```

Might be in this loop :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name =$record[username];
        $id = $record[id];
        $nmb_products = $record[nmb_products];
        $total_value = $record[total_value];
        $order_date = $record[order_date];
        $city = $record[dest_city];
        $address = $record[address];
    }
}
```

Like :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name =$record[username];
        $id = $record[id];
        $nmb_products = $record[nmb_products];
        $total_value = $record[total_value];
        $order_date = $record[order_date];
        $city = $record[dest_city];
        $address = $record[address];



        $sql[1] = "INSERT INTO ordered (username,nmb_products,product_id,total_value, city, address) VALUES ('$name', '$nmb_products', '$id', '$total_value', '$city', '$address')";
        $sql[2] = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE username='$username'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql[1]) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql[2]))
        { 
            /*header("Location:mypurchases.php");
            exit();*/
            //Do something
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: the `header(); exit();` inside the loop will surely help.

Comment: Yes . It's a mistake... 
My answer just gives the logic to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
You must put all the datas in the query :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $sql[1]='';
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $name =$record[username];
        $id = $record[id];
        $nmb_products = $record[nmb_products];
        $total_value = $record[total_value];
        $order_date = $record[order_date];
        $city = $record[dest_city];
        $address = $record[address];
        $sql[1].=" INSERT INTO ordered (username,nmb_products,product_id,total_value, city, address) VALUES ('$name', '$nmb_products', '$id', '$total_value', '$city', '$address');";
    }
}
else echo "Failed Access";


$sql[2] = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE username='$username'";
if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql[1]) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql[2]))
{ 
    header("Location:mypurchases.php");
    exit();
} 
}
```

Comment: use mysqli_multi_query